Dynamic environment name using variables not working
I need to deploy on a specific environment based on the tag of a Docker image.
What I've done so far:
parameters:    
  - name: vmToDeploy
    displayName: Environment Resource VM
    type: string
    default: ''

stages:
- stage: Deployment
  displayName:  Deployment
  jobs:
  - job: DeploymentTypeJob
    displayName: ️ Determine Deployment Type
    steps: 
      - task: Bash@3
        displayName: ️ Determine deployment type
        continueOnError: true
        name: DeploymentTypeJobTask
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            # All business logic here
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IsDocker;isOutput=true]true"
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DockerImage;isOutput=true]foo/bar:qa.1234"
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=EnvironmentName;isOutput=true]QA"
          workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
          failOnStderr: true
  - deployment:
    dependsOn: DeploymentTypeJob
    variables:
      IsDocker: $[ dependencies.DeploymentTypeJob.outputs['DeploymentTypeJobTask.IsDocker'] ]
      EnvironmentName: $[ dependencies.DeploymentTypeJob.outputs['DeploymentTypeJobTask.EnvironmentName'] ]
      DockerImage: $[ dependencies.DeploymentTypeJob.outputs['DeploymentTypeJobTask.DockerImage'] ]
    displayName: Deploy on ${{ variables.Deployment.EnvironmentName }} environment
    environment: 
     name: ${{ variables.EnvironmentName }}
     ${{ if ne(parameters['vmToDeploy'], '') }}:
       resourceName: ${{ parameters.vmToDeploy }}
     resourceType: VirtualMachine
    # Ensures to find only one artifact
    workspace:
      clean: all
    strategy: 
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - tasks: ...

Results in:
/deploy/docker.yml@templates (Line: 73, Col: 7): Environment name cannot contain resourceName 'DeploymentTypeJob' if resourceName is explicitly specified 'my-vm'.

Any reason why? I've read several topics around that subject but still can't manage to have something working.

Where is the qa in foo/bar:qa.1234 coming from? Is it possible to calculate that value based on something that is available at compile time like a predefined variable as $(Build.SourceBranch)?

Does the below answer help solving your issue?

An environment is a protected resource that might have approvals and checks defined, so its value must be known at compile time (before the pipeline runs).
You can either use parameters:
parameters:
  - name: environment
    type: string
    default: dev
    values:
      - dev
      - qa
      - prod

# ...

stages
  # ...

  - stage: DeployStage
    jobs:
      - deployment: Deploy
        environment: ${{ parameters.environment }}
        # ...

Or a variable that is available at compile time:
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  environment: prod

# ...

stages
  # ...
  - stage: DeployStage
    jobs:
      - deployment: Deploy
        environment: ${{ variables.environment }}
        # ...

Template expressions such as ${{ if ... }}, etc are evaluated at compile time so these can be used as well to set a variable or dynamically load a variables template:
variables:
  - template: /pipelines/variables/${{ parameters.environment }}-variables.yaml

Or:
variables:
  ${{ if contains(variables[‘Build.SourceBranch’], 'qa') }}:
    - template: /pipelines/variables/qa-variables.yaml
  ${{ else }}:
    - template: ...

